# Why does EF DetectChanges() actually modify objects?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Up until now I've let EF ChangeTracker do whatever it needs to do behind the scenes, but I'm here forced to intervene because it's actually modifying the properties on my objects:

```
db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
var loadedEntity = db.SomeEntity.Include(e => e.SomeChildren);

//modify the loadedEntity in some way

//if I debug and inspect 'loadedEntity' here, everything looks good!

db.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

//if I inspect here, the properties inside 'loadedEntity' have changed!
```

In my case, EF has for some reason nulled a foreign key on one of the children which is causing me problems. This key was correct in debug before DetectChanges() was called.

Is what's showing in debug incorrect, or does DetectChanges() actually modify the object behind the scenes? It's not clear why this is happening, so I'm trying to gain an understanding.

I previously assumed ChangeTracker simply kept its own list/values of original and new properties and figured it what needed to do when SaveChanges() was called? I wouldn't expect the tracker to modify the objects themselves.

```
(Entity Framework 6.1.3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess.

There are entities referenced by **SomeChildern** and I think Lazy loading is enabled in the application. According to documentation header of **Include** it is returning **IQueriable** so you need to call **.ToList** or **.Load** after Include so that the elements will be fetched from the database.

```
DbContext.Entry(someEntity).Include(e => e.SomeChildren).Load();
```

Comment: Hmm I've actually just tried forcing "db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;" but I still get the same problem. Is that sufficient or is a .ToList/.Load still needed?

Comment: add the code of line I mentioned in the answer. It should work

Comment: db.Entry().Include() isn't an option in this version so I need to use Reference() and Collection() instead - currently trying to figure out how to select children with the latter. Is there a valid reason why LazyLoadingEnabled = false may not produce the same behavior do you think?

Comment: It's definitely EF interfering to NULL the relationship. If I manually set a random foreign key, it doesn't modify it when DetectChanges() is called, but if I manually set a valid foreign key which exists, it steps in and NULLs it.